# Python34 syntax error?

Tags: python

I typed `python` in the shell; it gives me
NameError: name 'python' is not defined

And I've read the readme.txt and can't find a directory named PCBuild/
and I've tried to go to the python website too, maybe it's directory problem
I'm very sure it's in my `C:\Python34` path, and this error is the result

OK, I'm trying to finish a course at my ipad(Learn Programming: Coding Tutorial)
hopefully I get a certificate but the video he showed is using python 2.x
something is missing from the docs.
Can anyone help me what's the difference to type python in version 2.x and version 3.4
and at 3.4 I can't type python as well it says invalid syntax

```
Python 3.4.0rc1 (v3.4.0rc1:5e088cea8660, Feb 11 2014, 05:54:25) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> python3.4
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> set path=%path;C:\python34
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module> python
NameError: name 'python' is not defined
>>> Python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module> Python
NameError: name 'Python' is not defined
```

Comment: This is *not* a Python problem.  You are having trouble with your shell.

Comment: ok i'll try to shutdown comodo internet security premium

Comment: i tried typing python again but the NameError is still there

Comment: You are already in the python shell. You don't need to type python.

Comment: The commands you try to execute are meant for the OS Shell (which is cmd.exe on windows) to start the python interpreter. You are trying to enter them into the python interpreter shell, which of course produces an error...

Comment: like i said that guy in the video told me to install django but his version installing django from python is different from python34 in windows, i'm sure the valid command is wrong

Answer (score 2):

You are actually very close: you are trying to execute the python interpreter within the python shell. That will not work.

The ">>>" is the python prompt (or the prompt of the python shell).

you can use it to execute python code, but not the python interpreter :-)

```
Python 3.3.2+ (default, Oct  9 2013, 14:50:09) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("hello")
hello
>>>
```

`print("hello")` is an example for python code

**NameError** is already a message from the python interpreter.

You can use the Python interpreter in interactive mode - as you do right now, or you can call the python interprteter with a script name and the script will be executed:

```
python myscript.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 set path=%path%;C:\python34
```

(i.e. an extra percent sign)

Comment: >>> set path=%path%C:\python 34 File "stdin>", line 1 set path=%path%;C:\python34 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You took out the semicolon.

Comment: And you're in the Python shell already (as smarter people than I already noted).

Answer (score 0):

`python`, `python3.4`, etc. are meant to be typed into the *commandline*, not the Python shell.  They are aliases to the executable for the Python shell.

You would use them as follows (on Linux):

```
$ python /home/path/to/script.py
```

The above command would execute the Python script `script.py`.

Or, you could just do:

```
$ python
```

to launch the Python shell itself.

Comment: yes in the video, the guy is on Mac and he could type python in the shell but i'm just curious i can't type it in windows

Answer (score 0):

You are already in the python shell.  You should now start executing valid python commands.  Unfortunately, `python` is not a valid python command.

If you were to type `exit()`, you would go back to the shell you started with.  You could then retype `python` to go back into the python shell.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to install django, somewhere in the web i read says i have to install python could you show me the valid python commands to install django for windows, i have installed java and visual c++ as well i don't think i need cygwin just to install django

Comment: there are several sources, e.g.: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/WindowsInstall

Comment: oh god Assuming you have Python 2.4 or Python 2.5, exemaker, and the svn Subversion command-line client..i can't handle this just to install django in windows it's so hard

Comment: I've never installed django, but I am 100% confident that you don't actually use *python* commands to install it.  You would use some other tool (that might call python internally), but you wouldn't do it from within python itself.